# How to set up Laravel project to cPanel?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

#1
I'm trying to set up a laravel project as a subdomain on cpanel but I'm getting parsing issues, and an error.

These are the steps I've done so far
zip the project and upload it to this directory public_html/encuestas
unzip and move contents to the directory above
get ssh access with PuTTY and cd into the directory
do this command in PuTTY composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
I've also done it all through the PuTTY, cloned the repository from bitbucket with the same results.

After the command I get this feedback

vc@un.net [~/public_html/encuestas]# composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/vc/public_html/encuestas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500

Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your composer server, try to upload vendor to cpanel too.

Comment: seems you have a lower version of PHP on the server than you need

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered uploading the entire laravel project directory to your subdomain? I have hosted several projects on the cpanel by uploading the project folder to the public_html directory, setting up the database, and updating the .env credentials and everything worked fine. So if you can't do it by cloning the project through the terminal, you can try uploading the project directly using FileZilla to the sub-domain home directory then doing the configuration.